# legend indicator color not change with bar color in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am working with Google charts. I wanted to change the bar colors in chart. So using series style I have changed the bar color. But at same time I wanted to change Legend indicator color also as per bar color. But I am unable to change legend indicator color. Please help me.

here is chart code:

```js
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);
      function drawChart3() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Priority', 'Resolution(%)',{ role: 'annotation' },'ESL(%)',{ role: 'annotation' },{ role: 'style' }],
            ['P1', <%=P1_PERCENT %>,<%=P1_PERCENT%>,95,95,'color: #fcb441' ],
            ['P2', <%=P2_PERCENT%>,<%=P2_PERCENT%>,95,95,'color: #fcb441' ],
            ['P3 & P4', <%=P3_P4_PERCENT%>,<%=P3_P4_PERCENT%>,90,90,'color: #fcb441' ]
            ]);

        var options = {
          tooltip:{textStyle:{fontName:'"Arial"'}},
          title: 'Resolution(Priority Wise)',titleTextStyle:{fontName:'"Arial"'},
          hAxis: {title: 'Priority', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize:'15',fontName:'"Arial"'}},
          vAxis: {minValue:0},
          legend:{position: 'bottom'},
          chartArea:{width:'88%'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('g4'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

I am getting chart like this

[image: Result chart]

Comment: Legend color is determined by series color, which you are overriding by setting colors for individual bars.  If you want all of the bars of a given series to be the same color, set the `colors` or `series.<series index>.color` options instead of using the style column.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As *@asgallant* explained in his comment, if you want the same colors for the bars and the legend, you have to overwrite the default color series and not the color of the bars.
To do this, in the options object, add the `color` property which will contain your custom color series (array). In your case:

```
var options = {
      tooltip:{textStyle:{fontName:'"Arial"'}},
      title: 'Resolution(Priority Wise)',titleTextStyle:{fontName:'"Arial"'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Priority', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black',fontSize:'15',fontName:'"Arial"'}},
      vAxis: {minValue:0},
      legend:{position: 'bottom'},
      chartArea:{width:'88%'},
      colors: ['#fcb441', 'blue']
    };
```